# Null hypothesis with values seems way too simple for the marks given

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A random sample of $n=12$ observations from a normal population produced the following
estimates: estimate of population mean $= 47.1$ and estimate of population variance $=4.7$. Test the null hypothesis $H_0: m = 48$ against the alternative $H_a: m \neq 48$ at the $5\%$
level.

So this looked pretty simple, I used the normal distribution with the values $\frac{(48-47.1)12^{1/2}}{{4.7}^{1/2}}=1.44$ and read from table that that goes to $0.663%$, So as $0.6628-0.5=0.1628$ is $>0.05$ It is valid.
But the question was worth loads of marks so I must be missing something or have done it wrong?

Comment: Your $H_0$ should be $\mu=47$.

Comment: It says 48 on a past paper

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Why should the null hypothesis be that the population mean is 47?  I see nothing in the question which indicates that this is what is being asked.

Comment: I must have massively misunderstood the question ^^ I'll see what else I can do

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the smoke mean is equal to the population mean and the the difference between the two is due to sampling error.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm clearly going to need to go through some stuff cos I obviously don't understand it ^^

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Smoke mean? What is a smoke mean and why does it equal 47? And why is that the only choice for the null hypothesis?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen "smoke" is a weird phone substitution for "sample". The null hypothesis is noisy often a statement of no difference. Here, the lack of difference is between the value of the sample mean and value of the population mean.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern The sample mean here is $47.1$ and not $47.$ More importantly, your understanding is incorrect. The question makes perfect sense with a null hypothesis of $\mu =48.$ The null hypothesis you are testing is chosen at the outset of the experiment, before the sample mean is even known. “The sample mean is equal to the population mean” does not even make sense as a hypothesis as its truth varies from experiment to experiment.

Comment: I initially read the population mean as being 47. I think I confused the population mean with the population variance, since they are 47 .1 and 47, respectively.

Comment: If you want to discuss  this further, we can do so in chat.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:
$$t=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}=\frac{47.1-48}{\sqrt{4.7}/\sqrt{12}}=-1.44.$$
$$t_{0.025;11}=2.2.$$
$$|t|<t_{0.025;11} \Rightarrow \text{Do not reject } H_0.$$
You must use $t$-distribution, because $n=12$ is a small sample.

Comment: You are given the population variance, $\sigma^2$, and, not the sample standard deviation, $s$..

Comment: it the variance$^2$ not $=$ to the standard deviation?

Comment: And what it that $t_{0.025;11}$ called? I don't see where it's come from. (I've looked through my notes, but it's too hard to make sense of this.

Comment: Standard deviation is equal to the square root of variance. So, the sample standard deviation is: $s=\sqrt{s^2}$.

Comment: When the sample size is small $(n<30)$, $t$ table must be used instead of $z$ table. $t_{0.025;11}$ is $t$-value with $11$ degrees of freedom such that its right tail has area $0.025$.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense, but confused about the right tail area, is that a standard T graph property? However When I read of the T table, with $11$ degrees of freedom, I get $0.9$, which is $<0.95$ So I dont reject, but still confused where the $2.2$ came from since I got $0.9$.

Comment: Note: $t_{0.025;11}=2.2 \iff P(t>t_{0.025;11})=0.025$. Usually $t$ and $z$ tables are used differently...

Comment: So does this mean I've done it wrong?

Comment: I think it means it is not "way too simple  for the marks given".